# What would be the best way to verify a user uploaded file?

Tags: php, security, file

After a file has been uploaded to the tmp folder, for example a pdf file, would php [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo) mime check be enough to verify that the file is indeed a pdf file and is not infected?

How do you verify that a user uploaded file has no virus?

so that I could let users download it?

My scenario is this:
A user uploads a pdf file, I then let another user read his pdf file.

Comment: Virus doesn't matter at all.  Unless (1) you're going to execute an uploaded file.  Or (2) you're going to then download the file to someone else.  Which are you going to do?

Comment: for a pdf file, I would definitely let someone else view it.

Comment: It helps to **update** the question to provide the entire use case.  Some web applications accept an upload but do **not** then download the file.

Comment: @S.Lott Oh sorry for that, updating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> php fileinfo mime check be enough to verify that the file is indeed a pdf file and is not infected

No. It will tell you if it looks like a PDF file, but do no virus checking.

> How do you verify that a user uploaded file has no virus?

With a virus scanner. There are plenty of commercial and non-commercial packages out there.

Comment: I thought php fileinfo checks the file info, and has nothing to do with browsers.

Comment: Oh. I misread, I thought you were talking about the data received in the request. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Is installing the virus scanner enough? or do I need to run it on every upload? if so, then how?

Comment: You have to run it on every upload. How you do that depends on what interfaces the virus scanner provides. Make sure you pick one that has either a PHP API or a command line interface (the latter are likely to be much more common).

Answer (score 0):

A mime check does not guarantee anything, to be reasonably sure that a file has no virus, you will have to pass it through a virus scanner, like for example clam on linux.